# Problema con dex en Android

Tags: android

¿Hola, alguien ha tenido este problema en su aplicación android?

> Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed
>   64K. Learn how to resolve this issue at

He leído  en https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html de que se trata pero en mi desarrollo no aplica nada de esto que pudiese arrojar el error.

Lo único que hice en la aplicación fue actualizar en Gradle app la versión de play services de 8.3.0 a la 10.0.1 y al ejecutar la aplicación me envía ese error.

No tengo muchos métodos como en la documentación indica, ya hice lo que sugieren pero sigue enviando el mismo error.

Espero y puedan ayudar.

Comment: Gracias Miguel, ya había intentado eso. Hice todo lo que la documentación menciona. Me envía este error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: Agregaste tambien en tus dependencias `dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}`?

Comment: Si, he hecho todo lo de la documentación. Incluso sobrescribí:   @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

Comment: Lo raro es que cuando me regreso a la versión de google services 8.3.0 vuelve a funcionar.

Comment: ya intentaste **Clean** a tu proyecto?

Comment: Ya,  Clean y Rebuild...todo. He aplicado todo las sugerencias de stackoverflow y nada. Y solo actualicé  la versión, no hice nada más.

Comment: @Hector, si no funciono te recomiendo agregues tu build.gradle para revisarlo. Revisa mi respuesta para que veas dentro de que estructura tienes que habilitar la propiedad multiDexEnabled .

Comment: @Elenasys de hecho ya dijo que uso lo de multidex, ya que yo le di esa respuesta pero la elimine debido a que dijo que ya hizo eso.

Comment: Lo realizo pero posiblemente no lo agrego en la estructra correcta

Comment: @Hector agregue la corrección a tu archivo, revisa la actualización a mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

> Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed
>   64K. Learn how to resolve this issue at

Esto se soluciona habilitando multidex desde tu `build.gradle` :

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ...
        multiDexEnabled = true
    } 
}
```

Revisa el documento de la documentación : [**Configurar tu app para Multidex con gradle.**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html?hl=es-419)

> Los archivos de aplicación de Android (APK) contienen archivos de
>   código de bytes ejecutables en forma de archivos Dalvik Executable
>   (Dex), que contienen el código compilado empleado para ejecutar tu
>   app. La especificación de Dalvik Executable limita la cantidad total
>   de métodos a los que se puede hacer referencia en un archivo Dex a 65
>   536, incluidos los métodos del framework de Android, de biblioteca y
>   de tu propio código. En el contexto de la informática, el término
>   Kilo, K, denota 1024 (o 2^10). Debido a que 65 536 es igual a 64 X
>   1024, este límite se denomina **“límite de referencia de 64K”**.
>
> **Para superar este límite, debes configurar el proceso de compilación
>   de tu app para que genere más de un archivo Dex, lo que se conoce como
>   configuración MultiDex.**

---

El problema como comentaba es una incorrecta configuración debe ser

```
multiDexEnabled = true
```

escribiste incorrectamente

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Este sería tu archivo `build.gradle` corregido:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.kofh.mx.tae"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 6
            versionName "1.5"
            // Enabling multidex support.
            //multiDexEnabled true
            multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    dexOptions {
         javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.5.0-jar-with-dependenc‌​ies.jar')
    compile files('libs/usbsdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/jasypt-1.9.2.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

**Actualización:**, surgio otro problema que es:

> Error:UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR: Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC
>   overhead limit exceeded Error:Execution failed for task

Para esto se tiene que asignar mas memoria por lo tanto se configura el Heap size en el archivo `build.gradle` por medio de la variable `javaMaxHeapSize` :

```
  dexOptions {
         javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

Comment: `código`
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kofh.mx.tae"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.5"

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

Comment: buildTypes {  
        release {  
            minifyEnabled true  
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'  
        }  

    }  
}

Comment: dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.5.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/usbsdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/jasypt-1.9.2.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'

Comment: compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Disculpen las respuestas pero no he hallado la forma de ponerlo formateado. :)

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys, lo escribí tal cual está en la documentación y que viene sin el signo de = . Ya lo cambié y me está dando el mismo error al compilar:
Error:UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: @Hector eso es un error completamente diferente, no tiene que ver con el primero, revisa mi actualización y en el build.gradle esta agregada la variable javaMaxHeapSize.

Comment: @Elensys, gracias. Y sí, es un error diferente pero eso es derivado de la modificación del código. Ya había intentado también con javaMaxHeapSize "4g" y nada. Quizá me faltó extenderme en todo lo que he modificado. Otra cosa que también hice fue Extender MultiDexApplication -->public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { . También incluí el @ Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base ) { 
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);